# Relation between the order of subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let be $K, H $ subgroups of finite group $G$ such that $|H|,|K|>\sqrt{|G|}$. Show that $|H \cap K|>1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite clear once you show the formula
$$|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$$
since
$$|H \cap K| = \frac{|H||K|}{|HK|} > \frac{|G|}{|G|} = 1$$

Comment: I tried use that, but I don't had success.

Answer (score 3):

since there are more than $|G|$ pairs $(h,k)$ we must have $hk = h'k'$ for some $h \ne h', k \ne k'$

hence $h^{-1}h'=kk'^{-1} \ne 1_G$

Answer (score 0):

If we think of the orders
$|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$

If $|H\cap G|>1$ $\implies$  $|HK|>|G|$ ! And that's a contradiction

Comment: But HK is not, necessarily, subgroup of G.

Comment: Yes , my fault. The argument holds however with a change of notation

Comment: The order of |HK|, when HK is not subgroup of G, should be minor that |G|?Why?

Comment: Because $HK$ is a subset of G, so $HK$ can't have a greater cardinality.

You can define $HK$ merely as a subset of $G$


$\forall$ hk $\in HK$ $ $   $hk \in G$

Comment: "If $|H\cap G|>1$ $\implies$  $|HK|>|G|$" then what? $\;$

Comment: You've found that a subset of G has greater cardinality that G. That's not possible.

Comment: Not necessarily. $\:$ If $H$ is the trivial subgroup then $|H\cap G|>1$ $\implies$  $|HK|>|G|$ holds vacuously. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: $H\cap G$=<1> how can its cardinal be bigger that 1?

Comment: If $\;\;\; H\cap G \: = \: \{1\} \;\;\;$ then it's cardinal _won't_ be bigger than 1, which is why the implication $\hspace{.3 in} |H\cap G|>1$ $\implies$  $|HK|>|G| \;\;\;$ will hold vacuously. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$